# How do I write the each word into one single cels?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write data from json file to CSV file using python. My code is like this:

```
CSVFile1 = open('Group_A_participant_1_1.csv', 'a')
writeCSV1 = csv.writer(CSVFile1)

for file in data['annotations'][3]['instances']:
    var = file['arguments'].get('argument1')
    writeCSV1.writerow(var)
CSVFile.close()
```

My output is:
[image]

So my problem is that I can not see the whole word in one cell.

Thanks your helps inn advance!

I expect to get each word in one single cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
writeCSV1.writerow(var)
```

to

```
writeCSV1.writerow([var])
```

so you're writing an one-item list with your `var` instead of having the CSV module interpret `var`, a string, as separate characters.

For instance:

```
import csv
import sys

writeCSV1 = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

data = {
    "annotations": [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {
            "instances": [
                {"arguments": {"argument1": "foo"}},
                {"arguments": {"argument1": "bar"}},
            ]
        },
    ],
}

for file in data["annotations"][3]["instances"]:
    var = file["arguments"].get("argument1")
    writeCSV1.writerow([var])
```

prints out

```
foo
bar
```

whereas taking the brackets out from around `[var]` results in

```
f,o,o
b,a,r
```

as you described.

Comment: It does not work!

Comment: @Glory What does it do? What does it not do? What happens?

Comment: What happens is that I get an empty CSV file with nothing in it.

Comment: That certainly won't happen with just that change if your input data is the same.

Comment: The input data is the same. It is a little strange, but it as as I described.

Comment: Please see my edit for proof. I don't know what your original `data` is so I had to improvise.

Comment: I did get them now. Thank you! I do not know what the problem was but know it is working.

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on the first cell of the column where you want the converted
   names to appear (B2).
2. Type equal sign (=), followed by the text “Prof. “, followed by an
   ampersand (&).
3. Select the cell containing the first name (A2).
4. Press the Return Key.
5. You will notice that the title “Prof.” is added before the first name in the list.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way..?